# java draw arc tangent to line

Tags: java, math

I have a line, with a `startPoint` p1 (x,y) and an `endPoint` p2 (x,y). I want to draw an arc, with its `startPoint` being p2, to an `endPoint` p3 (x,y). the radius of the circle of which the arc is a part of is known. What  I'm trying to achieve:

[image: example]

in the picture above, ignore the letters. I took this image from google images.

How can i draw an arc with know `radius` r, `startPoint` (end point of line L) and `endPoint`, `tangent` to line L?

edit:

I know how to draw an arc, I just don't know how to draw an arc tangent to the endpoint of the line.

update:
I found another perfect example picture:

[image: example 2]

this image came from w3schools, i'm trying to achieve pretty much the same thing.
[w3schools url](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_arcto.asp)

Comment: Use JavaFX [Arc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Arc.html)

Comment: @M.leRutte please elaborate more? this does not help at all

Comment: I think you can draw your shape with the JavaFX framework, which is the modern day replacement for AWT and Swing. Although I recommended an Arc, maybe a `Path` with an `ArcTo` is more applicable. The [JavaDoc of ArcTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/ArcTo.html) has visual examples of how to draw. I'm sorry that I don't have a direct answer for you, just a suggestion. If you were asking for the math to do this then I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @M.leRutte Well, i know how to draw an arc, but i don't know how to configure it's starting angle in a way that the endPoint of the line is tangent to the arc

Comment: Maybe update your question with what you have and what you need. I obviously misunderstood your request.

Comment: It seems like it should be relatively simple geometry. Wouldn't it just be finding the center point r units away from the end point and along another line which is normal to the start line. Then you just use the angle of the line to determine where to start your arc. Using your example pic, QC is normal to QB. C is r away from Q. QB has an angle of 0. Start the arc at an angle of straight down + 0.

Comment: @TheCrzyMan could you write this in an answer, with some examples?

Comment: Pythagoras is your friend

Comment: Nah, @MBo beat me to it. And did way better than I would have

Answer (score 1):

You have points P1, P2, P3 and vector

```
D = P2 - P1   //(x2-x1, y2-y1)
```

get unit vector

```
uD = D / Length(D)
```

and perpendicular unit vector

```
uP = (-uD.y, uD.x)
```

Check needed direction of perpendicular

```
dp = uP.dot.(x3-x1, y3-y1)
```

if  dp is negative, negate uP vector to provide correct position of the circle center

Then find circle center

```
C = P2 + uP * Radius
```

If you need starting and ending angles to form an arc, calculate them using atan2 (ArcTan2) function

```
P2C = P2 - C  //really -uP*radius
A2 = atan2(P2C.y, P2C.x)

P3C = P3 - C
A3 = atan2(P3C.y, P3C.x)
```

Comment: for the unit vector part, which type is uD? also, what is length(D), isnt D a point(x,y)?

Comment: uD is vector with two components. `what is length(D)` - seems you need a book about vector algebra basics.

Comment: so, in java D and uD would be a Vector2D?

Comment: Yes. Note that that class has method `length` (but `normalize` approach is better).

Comment: awesome, thanks. is there any chance you could update your answer using javax.vecmath.Vector2d? so ie: `Vector2d D = new Vector2d(P2.x-P1.x,P2.y-P1.y);` im also working on that right now, but i think i will make mistakes

Comment: i Dont know how to translate `dp = uP.dot.(x3-x1, y3-y1) `

Comment: I don't know java enough to write code. Just define good initial points for easy checking at every step.. For example (0,0), (2,0), (4,2)

Comment: use Vector2D method `dot` to get scalar product of two vectors

Comment: alright. do you know how to write the `dp = uP.dot.(x3-x1, y3-y1)` part with `Vector2D.dot(Vector2D v1)` ? `Vector2D.dot.(x3-x1,y3-y1)` is not possible

Comment: I suspect dp=uP.dot(P13) where P13 is previously made vector2d

Comment: with P13 being: `Vector2d P13 = new Vector2d(x3-x1,y3-y1)` ?